# What is the best action after OP rolls back the post to the low quality original?

Tags: support, edits, flags, low-quality-posts, rollbacks

I edited an answer (**improved its format**) several times and after that OP pasted back to original post (**low quality post**) or added one space (**he didn't add any value to his answer**). What is the best action for that situation?

1. give downvote
2. edit post again
3. edit post again and give downvote
4. flag as a low quality answer.
5. flag as in need of moderator intervention
6. something else

Comment: What kind of low quality are we talking here? Sparse (but not unreadable or entirely missing) explanation? Code-only answer? Confused jumble of bizarre formatting and messy writing that is very difficult to read?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Let's say code-only answer.

Comment: In this specific case, your edit wasn't really needed, author probaby got upset by seeing someone else "touching" his code thus rolled back. Your later rollbacks also removed the link to jsfiddle, which isn't good. All in all, nothing you should be doing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you for your answer. I think I didn't remove the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Not on purpose, I know, but you did by rolling back to your first edit that you made before author added that link.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't notice that. Maybe, I did mistake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A code-only answer usually lacks sufficient explanation, and is probably not a very good answer anyway.  Instead of trying to pick a fight with an uncooperative contributor of low-quality posts, I suggest that you post a better answer yourself, with good formatting, and more importantly, an explanation.

The original poster would then have a good answer, your post would set a good example, and hopefully the voting system would accord the appropriate reputation changes to each of you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not a fight and the post  is already marked as an answer and I don't need to answer it again.

Comment: Are you referring to [this edit war](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34408238/revisions)? If so, I think that you are both wasting your time.

Comment: ha ha ha. I don't call it edit war because I edited two times and after that I gave downvote. I want to know what is the best action for that situation?

Comment: You don't have any substantial improvement to offer, so just leave it. I don't even think it's worth downvoting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. Let me wait to see others opinion.

Comment: @alirezasafian ... and downvote it.

Comment: @Braiam I did, but I want to know what the best action is.

Answer (score 5):

In general, and to add to 200 success' answer, Down vote, move away. Don't engage. If this is a rollback war, it will get an auto-flag for moderators. People will notice on the front page as well.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer.

Comment: Let me mark @200_success' post as an answer  because he answered first.

Answer (score 4):

My own $0.02 are:

1. After the first rollback by the author add a comment explaining why you did the edit, how it improves the post, and ask the author to apply those edits again.
2. If you get no response after a while, roll back to the last valid revision, making sure you don't overwrite other edits made in the meanwhile.
3. If the author rolls back yet again, downvote, flag as VLQ if the post becomes very low quality, and walk away - it's not worth your time.

If you notice this behavior for other posts by the same user, all resulting in low quality contents, I would even advice to flag one of the posts as "Other", explain what's going on, and moderators can suspend the user - there is a special suspension reason for this. (*This account has been suspended because of low-quality contributions*)

Comment: Thanks again. You make a difficult situation for me. All answers are really perfect. Now, how can I accept three answer? :'(

Comment: The extra flagging isn't really necessary. Moderators get automatic flags for rollback wars, defacing multiple posts and such. But overall, good advice :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 the point of the extra flag is to prevent the user from posting again, the chance that moderator handling a single "rollback war" will also check other posts by same user is pretty low.

Comment: @alirezasafian lol, there have been lots of discussions about this here in this very site, but you can safely leave this without any accepted answer. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard But generally, the flag will describe the situation as well. It's not a simple *This needs attention*, there's different reasons. One war shouldn't warrant a suspension, and there isn't anything a moderator *can* do if it's fixed. If it's multiple posts, or multiple wars, the flag will say that, and moderators will react accordingly.

Comment: @Zizouz212 that's hard to believe, you say this from experience as moderator? If so, kudos for the "smart flagging" system! :)

Comment: Well, not my experience (OS is *really* quiet, dare I say almost a ghost town with flags), but I remember seeing a meta post here or on Meta SO...

Comment: Here's one! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306821/4293417

Comment: @Zizouz212 hmm.. issue here though, is that the initial state of the post was of very low quality, it's not a case where the author posted something useful then defaced it with an edit.

Comment: I don't like to leave my question without any answer. Let me mark @200_success' post as an answer because he answered first.

Comment: Fair enough @ali - go ahead. :-)